# Button Click inside Fragment to open up new fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I don't know how to open up a new fragment on button click, I only know how to open new Activity using intent but when I try to open up new fragment my project app crashes hope someone can help me with my problem

this is what I have:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {


public FragmentTwo() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_two, container,
            false);

    // SPINNER1
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSpecialty);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity(), R.array.specialty_arrays,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    // SPINNER2
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocation);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity(), R.array.city_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

    // BUTTON
    Button btnSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnSearch:
                    //what to put here
                   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                   ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentThree());
                    ft.commit();
                 break;
                }
            }   
    });   

    return view;
}
```

}

LOGCAT:

```
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at          com.droid.FragmentThree.onCreateView(FragmentThree.java:30)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at  android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-01 03:45:25.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please ensure that you use android.app.FragmentManager and android.app.FragmentTransaction instead of their android.app.support.v4.* counterparts, which I see you were using before Vamshi's edit or you will get unexpected results

Comment: yeah I changed imports

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

From below code change id show_fragment to match with your layout XML id..

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnSearch:
                    //what to put here
                   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                   ft.replace(R.id.show_fragment, new TestFragment(), "fragment_screen");
                    ft.commit();
                 break;
                }
            }   


<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: in `ExampleFragment` I will put the Fragment I want to open after clicking button right ?

Comment: and what about R.id.fragment_container ? sorry im newbee

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html for more details  of fragments and as of replace your previous fragment id

Comment: I'm getting error in `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` and `replace`

Comment: send me the exception

Comment: `Change type of 'transaction' to 'FragmentTransaction'` and `Change to 'replace(..)'`

Answer (score 0):

Below piece of code help you to call new fragment on button click.

```
   Button btnSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSearch:
              FragmentHome home = new FragmentHome();  //this is your new fragment.
              FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
              ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, home);
              ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK);// it will anim while calling fragment.
              ft.addToBackStack(null); // it will manage back stack of fragments.
              ft.commit();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to open the fragment from fragment so dont forget getActivity().

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new fragmentClass())
                        .addToBackStack(null).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

R.id.content_frame -> id of the frame layout

fragmentClass      -> Your second fragment

finally

commit() or commitAllowingStateLoss()

Comment: I don't get that frame layout

Comment: so where u r going to replace?

Comment: It is the frame layout, ie for the FragmentActivity or sherlockFragmentActivity you might give some layout file right. in that file one frame layout should be there to replace fragment on that frame layout. u have to give that id here

Comment: so why R.id and not R.layout ? sorry new here

Comment: Fragment transaction needs that frame id. it is going to replace the fragment in that frame. so keep one frame and give that id here.