# Android Studio Main Activity That has a button and gets the Fragment layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

Is it possible to have a button in the main activity and when the user clicks 
it , the fragment layout will appear? Im new to Android Studio.If its possible
do you think you can show me an example of it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be similar to the description provided here in the link just add the button to the activity instead of the fragment in this example
[Button Click inside Fragment to open up new fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777928/button-click-inside-fragment-to-open-up-new-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it directly from the main activity like this example:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Click me"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.root_layout, new NewFragment());
                transaction.commit();
                //button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Where NewFragment is just a black fragment.

The problem is the LinearLayout is replaced, but the button is not:

[image: An activity with a fragment replacing the layout.]

So you can set the visibility (as a commented in the code). But I suggest to create 2 fragments, one with the button and one with your content. Then in the activity onCreate() method, you can set the first fragment and replace it with the other one later.

Comment: Thanks Alan, Also I have another question 
for some reason my fragment is being over lapped on my main activity
like for my main activity I have a welcome deal and when 
I select the fragment on the drawer it opens up the fragment but is being over lapped .how could I fix this?

Comment: I think you should open a new question, because we need to see your code and maybe a screenshot to check what could be wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096646/fragment-overlapping-my-main-activity

Comment: I just did I didnt know how to properly add my code this is my first time doing it